# magit-reset-quickly does not work anymore

Tags: magit

When in `magit-status` and having files in the "Unstaged changes" list I always could go to one of these files and press `x` to run `magit-reset-quickly` revert the changes on this file.

But now it does not work anymore. When I press `x` or run the commandy with `M-x` magit asks with "Reset master to:" and offers branches. But after I select a branch, nothing happens. The file is not reverted.

This is in all my repos and my config is this:

```lisp
(use-package magit
  :straight t)
```

So what could be the problem? Or how can I debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Reset" and "reverse" do not refer to the same action.

- Commits are *reset* using `git reset ...`. This changes what `HEAD` points at. Some variants additionally reset the files in the working tree.
- Individual files or hunks are *applied* or *reversed*. Reverting just means doing the opposite of what the patch says, i.e., remove `+` lines and add `-` lines.

In Magit <kbd>x</kbd> is used for resetting, <kbd>a</kbd> for applying, and **<kbd>v</kbd> for reversing**.

This is documented in https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Staging-and-Unstaging.html, https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Applying.html and https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Resetting.html.